# I somehow messed up package management and dependencies

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

likely by trying to run an old installer I must have really messed something up. This is what happens when I try to install steam on my Ubuntu 22.04:

```
$ sudo apt install steam
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libegl1 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libinput10 (>= 0.15.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
              Recommends: libqt5svg5 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: qt5-gtk-platformtheme but it is not going to be installed
 shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed but it is not going to be installed or
                        grub-efi-arm64-signed but it is not installable
               Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
 util-linux : PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

This is what happens whenever I try to install anything.

I have tried `update`/`upgrade`, `dist-upgrade`, `reinstall`, `fix-broken`, ... to no avail.

Also, `apt-mark showhold` returns nothing.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

---

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1)]/ jammy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security restricted main
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

.list files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d

```
google-chrome.list                      mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list        spotify.list.save
google-chrome.list.save                 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list.save   ubuntu-mozilla-security-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list  obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-jammy.list  ubuntu-mozilla-security-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list.save
mint-una.list                           signal-xenial.list
mint-una.list.save                      spotify.list
```

---

```
$ sudo apt install apt init libqt5gui5 libegl1 libgl1 libudev1 libqt5svg5 qt5-gtk-platformtheme  shim-signed grub2-common util-linux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
grub2-common is already the newest version (2.06-2ubuntu7).
init is already the newest version (1.62).
libegl1 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libegl1 set to manually installed.
libgl1 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libgl1 set to manually installed.
shim-signed is already the newest version (1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9).
util-linux is already the newest version (2.37.2-4ubuntu3).
util-linux set to manually installed.
libqt5svg5 is already the newest version (5.15.3-1).
libqt5svg5 set to manually installed.
apt is already the newest version (2.4.7).
apt set to manually installed.
libqt5gui5 is already the newest version (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1).
libqt5gui5 set to manually installed.
libudev1 is already the newest version (249.11-0ubuntu3.4).
libudev1 set to manually installed.
qt5-gtk-platformtheme is already the newest version (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1).
qt5-gtk-platformtheme set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

---

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                        
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                    
Hit:5 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease       
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]            
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                  
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy InRelease              
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease        
Fetched 110 kB in 1s (113 kB/s)                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

apt-cache policy libapt-pkg6.0
libapt-pkg6.0:
  Installed: 2.4.7
  Candidate: 2.4.7
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.7 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.5 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please show your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and any `.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: The first one of those that jumps out at me is the `mint-una.list` repo being enabled. Mint isn't Ubuntu, and it's really not a good idea to have repos for another distro enabled on Ubuntu. What's the contents of that file? Is it enabled?

Comment: It only contains the line "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com una upstream". I believe I added it to be able to install something from PPA rather than snap. I will try removing the source.

Comment: Removing the mint source, the mint .list files and updating didn't help unfortunately. Thx though

Comment: What happens if you try to force install everything it complains about? e.g. `sudo apt install apt init libqt5gui5 libegl1 libgl1 libudev1 libqt5svg5 qt5-gtk-platformtheme  shim-signed grub2-common util-linux` - what's the full output from that?

Comment: See output in posting above. This is what happens when I try to reinstall one of those packages:

sudo apt reinstall libapt-pkg6.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of libapt-pkg6.0 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `sudo apt update` and `apt-cache policy libapt-pkg6.0` in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sources.list` has `jammy-updates` commented out or missing. That's why some packages fail to install.

The 2.4.8 update to `libapt-pkg6.0` is in `jammy-updates/main`, which is among some commented out or missing lines in your `sources.list`.

You should have this as a minimum.

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Yes! I lost jammy-updates somehow ... everything is back to normal again ... thank you!